# Mac OS sees usb dongle as keyboard

Tags: macos, usb

I am trying to connect controller from [xkeys.com](http://xkey.com) to my mbp (10.11.5) the manual suggests me using controllermate.app and I have installed. When I plugin the interface, mac always sees the interface as a keyboard.

From controllermate it says. Controllermate driver is not being used, The driver at /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext is likely being used.

So is that possible reset this usb settings on macos and use controllermate's driver instead of IOHIDFamily.kext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got problem solved! Here is the answer: I used to use my xkey dongle on an Android table and the dongle has been assigned "Support text, mouse, multimedia macros". So I resetted the dongle and assigned "Supports game controller, mouse, multimedia macros". Now when plugin to mac, controllermate's driver still cannot be used but mac os sees xkey dongle as a game controller. Then all the buttons connected to the dongle are working.